# Class list Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, menu, click, nav

I would like to remove a class from one element when I clicked another?

could you help me please

```
<div class="tab">
    <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
</div>

<div class="tab">
    <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
</div>


    const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    dots.forEach(dot => dot.addEventListener('click', handleClick));

    function handleClick(e) {
        this.classList.toggle('open');
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            if (dots.classList.contains('open')) {
                dots.classList.remove('open');
            } else {
                dots.classList.add('open');
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `dots` is a `NodeList` ... you are almost there with your code ... `dots[i].classList` instead of `dots.classList` .... or `dots.forEach(dot => { if ......})` like you do with the addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
dots.forEach(dot => dot.addEventListener('click', () => {
  dots.forEach(dotEl => {
  if(dot !== dotEl) {
   dotEl.classList.toggle('open');
  }
  })
}));
```

```css
.open {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
</div>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

So now when a button is clicked then every other button's `classList` is toggled because we're only toggling it if it isn't the clicked button(I'm referring to the `if` condition).

Comment: Thank you for the clarity. Now I understand where I was wrong